# How to save data from summernote into SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how are you guys?

i have asp.net webform its for adding news in the news content i would like to use summernote http://summernote.org/ Super Simple WYSIWYG editor. as a WYSIWYG editor so could some one please help me to save the data from this editor

this is my code

```
<div class="form-body">
                                       <div class="form-group last">
                                           <label class="control-label col-md-2">News Content</label>
                                           <div class="col-md-10">
                                           <div name="summernote" id="summernote_1"> </div>
                                               <asp:label runat="server" text="Label" ID="news_con" ></asp:label>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
```

i can't get the text value from the summernote
by this code
news_con.Text = Request.Form["summernote_1"];

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `<textarea>` to handle this as opposed to a `<div>`? Usually they are a bit easier to use with respect to storing values (as they are designed to do so) :

```
<textarea id="txtTest" runat="server"></textarea>
```

One of the ways that you might handle this would be to register an event using [Summernote's available API](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/#api) to set the HTML content for your `<textarea>` element whenever focus was lost (e.g. the `onblur`) :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Set up your summernote instance
        $("#txtTest").summernote();
        // When the summernote instance loses focus, update the content of your <textarea>
        $("#txtTest").on('summernote.blur', function () {
            $('#txtTest').html($('#txtTest').summernote('code'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Since you are likely going to be storing HTML content within the element, you'll likely want to ensure that .NET doesn't think you are trying to exploit it. You can do this by either explicitly setting this page to ignore that process by updating the [`ValidateRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your page :

```
<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest = "false" %>
```

Or you could try simply escaping the content that is being set :

```
$('#txtTest').html(escape($('#txtTest').summernote('code')));
```